# Why my loss function or accuracy does not improve?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I have 3D CNN U-net architecture to solve segmentation problem. I am using Adam optimisation together with binary cross entropy and the metric is "accuracy". I try to understand why it does not improve.

```
Train on 2774 samples, validate on 694 samples
Epoch 1/20
2774/2774 [==============================] - 166s 60ms/step - loss: 0.5189 - acc: 0.7928 - val_loss: 0.5456 - val_acc: 0.7674

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.54555, saving model to model-tgs-salt-1.h5
Epoch 2/20
2774/2774 [==============================] - 170s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5170 - acc: 0.7928 - val_loss: 0.5485 - val_acc: 0.7674

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 0.54555
Epoch 3/20
2774/2774 [==============================] - 169s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5119 - acc: 0.7928 - val_loss: 0.5455 - val_acc: 0.7674

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 0.54555 to 0.54549, saving model to model-tgs-salt-1.h5
Epoch 4/20
2774/2774 [==============================] - 170s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5117 - acc: 0.7928 - val_loss: 0.5715 - val_acc: 0.7674

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 0.54549
Epoch 5/20
2774/2774 [==============================] - 169s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5126 - acc: 0.7928 - val_loss: 0.5566 - val_acc: 0.7674

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 0.54549
Epoch 6/20
2774/2774 [==============================] - 169s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5138 - acc: 0.7928 - val_loss: 0.5503 - val_acc: 0.7674

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.54549
Epoch 7/20
2774/2774 [==============================] - 170s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5103 - acc: 0.7928 - val_loss: 0.5444 - val_acc: 0.7674

Epoch 00007: val_loss improved from 0.54549 to 0.54436, saving model to model-tgs-salt-1.h5
Epoch 8/20
2774/2774 [==============================] - 169s 61ms/step - loss: 0.5137 - acc: 0.7928 - val_loss: 0.5454 - val_acc: 0.7674
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: If I gave you an answer would you believe me? You shouldn't. Without your code or a list of all your parameters (assuming you are doing everything else right) no one can help you.

Comment: @MeteHanKahraman I would believe you :)). I am not looking for a specific solution, I know this is not a right place to ask this question but I just wanted to discuss my problem. If someone experienced this issue in the past like me, I would love to listen that how he fixed it.

Comment: @VuralErdogan Did you manage to solve this problem, I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use batch size in your network. let's try to increase that. I think it could be useful in speed of train.

Comment: Speed is not a problem at the moment. But I will try that.